# SOQL - Relationship extract json from child object and join picklist label

Tags: soql, json, picklist, relationships

This [soql](/questions/tagged/soql)

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT CountryISOCode__c, Name, Role__c FROM Person__r)
FROM Market__c
```

returns a row that looks like this:

| Id | NAME | Person__r |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a081.. | C1 | [{"A":"foo", "Name":"P2", "Role__c":"PR4"},{"A":"bar", "Name":"P7", "Role__c":"PR7"}] |
| a081.. | C2 | [{"A":"Jam", "Name":"P6", "Role__c":"PR6"},{"A":"Yum", "Name":"P8", "Role__c":"PR5"}] |

The values in column `Person__r` do look like a json array.
The field `Role__c` is a picklist which can be queried like this

```
SELECT Value, Label, IsActive 
FROM PicklistValueInfo 
WHERE EntityParticle.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Person__c' 
      AND EntityParticle.QualifiedApiName = 'Role__c'
```

which returns

| Value | Label | isActive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PR3 | Ram | false |
| PR4 | Roo | true |
| PR5 | Rar | true |

I want to combine both queries and if possible create pivoted columns for every label for the picklist Role__c (Ram, Roo, Rar).

The final output should look like this

| MarketName | Ram | Roo | Rar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| C2 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| C7 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

For every market (C1, C2, C7) count how many persons (P2, P7, P6, P8) have which role (Ram, Roo, Rar)

Can this be done with SOQL?

Comment: Related [join 2 picklists](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/417512/join-two-different-picklists-on-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get something close to this using an [Aggregate Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm).

Your query would be:

`SELECT Market__r.Name, toLabel(Role__c), COUNT(Id) FROM Person__c GROUP BY Market__r.Name, Role__c`

(I'm guessing what the lookup/object names are here because you'll need to base the query on the person object not the market object)

Your result would look like:

| Market Name | Role | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | Ram | 2 |
| C1 | Rar | 1 |
| C2 | Ram | 2 |
| C2 | Roo | 3 |
| C7 | Roo | 1 |
| C7 | Rar | 1 |

Comment: The result works but it returns the columns `Market.Name, Role.Value, Count(Id)` example `C1, PR4, 1`. Is it possible from the picklist `Role__c` to display the `Role__c.Label` (`Ram, Rar, Roo`) instead of `Role__c.Value` (`PR3, PR4, PR5`)?

Comment: You can do `toLabel(Role__c)` to display the label instead of the value. (Just change it in the `SELECT` and not in the `GROUP BY`)

Comment: This does the trick. Thanks a lot.